# Flexbox alignment with image and nav menu

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: Sample Image]

Solution should look like image above when done.

I need some help with flexboxes. I am just learning and am stuck on something, I hope someone can provide some guidance. I am creating a page header using html and CSS only. In this header I have 3 different child items

1. a span for a logo that is left justified
2. a span for two lines of text [title and subtitle] that I want to appear immediately to the right of the logo and
3. the problem child, a navigation menu [horizonal, no drop-downs] that needs to appear in the center of the whole page and inline with the logo and title.

Here is some working code, just can't seem to get it right. Any help appreciated

**home.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<script src="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3data.js"></script>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/page-header.css">
</head>
<body>
<span w3-include-html="page-header.html"></span>
<script>
w3IncludeHTML()
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**page-header.html**

```
<span class="header-box">
<img class="header-logo" src="images\logo.svg" />
<span class="header-title">Company Title</span>
<span class="header-subtitle">best products</span>
<ul class="header-menu">
<li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
<li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Locations</a>/li>
<li class="nav-link"><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
</span>
```

**page-header.css**

```
@import url("https://use.typekit.net/xul0ipk.css");
.header-box {
padding: 0.5rem;
background-color: beige;
display: flex;
flex-flow: column nowrap;
justify-items: center;
align-items: center;
}
.header-logo {
display: flex;
flex-flow: inherit;
align-self: flex-start;
width: clamp(3.12rem, 2.8692rem + 2.674vw, 6.88rem);
background-color: blue;
}
.header-box span {
flex-flow: row;
display: inline-flex;
align-self: flex-start;
background-color: aliceblue;
}
.header-title {
display: flex;
}
```

Thanks in advance!!!

It should look something like this

Comment: We can't help you if you don't provide what's inside 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/page-header.css">`

Comment: You can restructure your html a bit, put your company title and best product in a div, and style those separately. Also, look into common flex values to give each column a different width.

Comment: Sorry Bernard, they were empty I just forgot to take them out of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using only [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), I made a rough, modified version of your code below. The [`flex`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#aa-flex) attribute (which consists of `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis`) is your best friend when needing to center inline flex elements!

**Edit:** Added semicolon after `flex: 40%` in header-column-2 and also changed `justify-content: center` to `justify-content: space-around` per @luenib's suggestion.

```css
@import url("https://use.typekit.net/xul0ipk.css");
.header-container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(142,195,221,0.5);
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 20px;
}

.header-column1 {
  flex: 30%;
  padding: 10px;
  gap: 10px;
  display: inherit;
  flex-flow: inherit;
  align-self: flex-start;
  align-items: inherit;
}

.header-column1-img {
  flex: 50%;
}

.header-column1-img img {
  width: 100%;
}

.header-column1-title {
  flex: 50%;
  gap: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.header-column2 {
  flex: 40%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  gap: 20px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  align-items: inherit;
}

.header-column2 li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.header-column3 {
  flex: 30%;
}
```

```html
<span class="header-container">
  <div class="header-column1">
    <div class="header-column1-img">
      <img src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5926db217034dc5f91becd6b/master/w_1904,c_limit/so-logo-s.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="header-column1-title">
      <span class="header-title">stackoverflow</span>
      <span class="header-subtitle">lorem ipsum</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul class="header-column2">
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
    <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">About</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="header-column3"></div>
</span>
```

Comment: Hi Paul, firstly, thanks for helping. I notice though that the menu is still not centered on the page horizontally. that's one of the things I couldn't get right. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Karlton! The menu in my example should be centered since both divs sandwiching it have the same flex-basis value (30%), although it may not look like it since the right div doesn't contain anything. If you want the menu to be centered in the remaining whitespace, you can remove the right div entirely and the menu should center in the remaining space!

Comment: @paul. Add justify-content: space-around; to your header-column2 class and now you'll have you menu items centered.

Comment: @luenib thanks! Updated the answer per your suggestion